# Android: xml or json?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm curious whether it's more convenient to use json or xml in my android applications? Or does it not matter?

In Flash apps it's definitely more convenient to use xml, but in javascript (at least in my opinion), it's more convenient to work with json. I have a rails backend that could conveniently give json or xml so I'm trying to make a choice now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the reason i ll recommend JSON not easy of use but the network bandwidth. JSON msgs are smaller in size as compared to XML. So consider this also for choosing one over the other.

Secondly, you can use [Gson another lib](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) also to ease your implementation which is easier to use as compared to `org.json` implementation that comes with Android platform.

Comment: it is in indeed, if you are ok with domain objects. Then you have only two lines of code to parse json...like `Gson gson = new Gson(); gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourDomainObject.class);` and it can handle collections n all too. I had used it so i know its easier to use than org.json that comes with Android platform.

Answer (score 2):

JSON would be very easy in Android. You already have libraries for it, whose Classes you can use to parse the JSON file or content.
There is some pain involved in parsing XML. I would suggest JSON. Let me know if  you need any examples of parsing using JSON.

Comment: yeah, @nithinreddy, hook me up with a clean simple example of json if you know of one. I was looking at the syntax and order of parsing xml and it doesn't seem straight forward, at least, not something I'm going to be able to do without always referring to examples...

Comment: Great tutorial at http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/  JSON is more comfortable and easy to work with than XML parsing (at least with my experience)

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK has both org.json or org.xml package so i think it is not a matter of Android sdk, but of your application/api design

Comment: thanks for the comment @Kurosawa. my api will easily serve up xml or json, so at this point i'm just trying to decide what's going to be convenient on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is very easy to use as comparing to XML.Android has support for both JSON and XML.A detailed example is already given here.This talks about when you go for JSON and XML

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-andbene1/

Hope this will help you.